# Autowired Annotation not working when using<context:annotation-config /> in ApplicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
  <context:annotation-config />
```

when above line is added in ApplicationContext.xml file the Test.java is not running but when i add this it works but in the [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/)  i was going through it says both the methods work can someone help whats the problem with 
above line of code.

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

> Employee.java

```
    package com.stp.beans;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

    public class Employee {
        private Address empaddress;

        public Address getEmpaddress() {
            return empaddress;
        }
        @Autowired
        public void setEmpaddress(Address empaddress) {
            this.empaddress = empaddress;
        }
    }
```

> Address.java

```
    package com.stp.beans;

    public class Address {
        private String address;

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }
    }
```

> ApplicationContext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <bean id ="empbean" class="com.stp.beans.Employee"></bean>
    <bean id ="adrbean" class="com.stp.beans.Address"></bean>
    </beans>
```

> Test.java

```
    package com.stp.test;

    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    import com.stp.beans.Employee;

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/com/stp/cfgs/ApplicationContext.xml");
            Employee emp = (Employee) context.getBean("empbean");
            System.out.println(emp.getEmpaddress());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh boy, there's a lot going on here. Neither `Employee` nor `Address` should be a Spring bean (they're data objects, not service objects), using `context:annotation-driven` was the correct thing to do in the first place, and more broadly, XML-based hand-configuration is generally the old way of doing things. Your tutorial is obsolete (by casting `getBean`, for example), and I recommend starting with the Spring Boot Getting Started guides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `<context:annotation-config />`, your **ApplicationContext.xml** should be like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />
<bean id ="empbean" class="com.stp.beans.Employee"></bean>
<bean id ="adrbean" class="com.stp.beans.Address"></bean>
</beans>
```

You had just missed the `context` related definitions.